# Most current version uploading locally but old version still remains on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

I've tried tons of things but can't figure it out... I can't find anything in the heroku logs, what could I be missing? This is the heroku logs..

I think it could be a problem in gemfile or gemfile.lock since it skips the gemfile.lock because of windows I think, but don't see how that would affect anything as it was updating fine earlier, thoughts?

EDIT: I've just realized that on my Huroku the name of my application is pinterestingx(pinterestingx.herokuapp.com) but when I git push heroku master my address bar says omr-pinterestingx.herokuapp.com so they don't match, might this be the problem? How can I solve this?

```
$ heroku logs
←[36m2014-01-24T05:26:36.093302+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   bin/rails:4:in `require'

←[36m2014-01-24T05:26:36.093043+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/
2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `tap'
←[36m2014-01-24T05:26:36.093302+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m [2014-01-24 05:26:36] INFO
  going to shutdown ...
←[36m2014-01-24T05:26:36.093302+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
←[36m2014-01-24T05:26:36.093773+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m [2014-01-24 05:26:36] INFO
  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
←[36m2014-01-24T05:26:36.093773+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Exiting
←[36m2014-01-24T05:26:36.562152+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Starting process with c
ommand `bin/rails server -p 12335 -e $RAILS_ENV`
←[36m2014-01-24T05:26:37.442566+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Process exited with sta
tus 143
←[36m2014-01-24T05:26:40.284565+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m [2014-01-24 05:26:40] INFO
  ruby 2.0.0 (2013-11-22) [x86_64-linux]
←[36m2014-01-24T05:26:40.284565+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m [2014-01-24 05:26:40] INFO
  WEBrick 1.3.1
←[36m2014-01-24T05:26:40.284565+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m [2014-01-24 05:26:40] INFO
  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2 port=12335
←[36m2014-01-24T05:26:40.557417+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m State changed from star
ting to up
←[36m2014-01-24T05:27:17.022181+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Started GET "/" for 108.22
7.81.48 at 2014-01-24 05:27:17 +0000
←[36m2014-01-24T05:27:17.022181+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m => Rails 4.0.0 application
 starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:12335
←[36m2014-01-24T05:27:17.022181+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m => Run `rails server -h` f
or more startup options
←[36m2014-01-24T05:27:17.022181+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Started GET "/" for 108.22
7.81.48 at 2014-01-24 05:27:17 +0000
←[36m2014-01-24T05:27:17.022181+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m => Booting WEBrick
←[36m2014-01-24T05:27:17.022181+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m => Ctrl-C to shutdown serv
er
←[36m2014-01-24T05:27:17.140538+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Processing by PinsControll
er#index as HTML
←[36m2014-01-24T05:27:17.140538+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Processing by PinsControll
er#index as HTML
←[33m2014-01-24T05:27:17.243058+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=info method=GET pat
h=/ host=omr-pinterestingx.herokuapp.com request_id=95dd9900-74ee-4861-8e51-3ec3
eedc9753 fwd="108.227.81.48" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=259ms status=304 byt
es=0
←[36m2014-01-24T05:27:17.232081+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   Rendered pins/index.html
.erb within layouts/application (64.3ms)
←[36m2014-01-24T05:27:17.232081+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   Rendered pins/index.html
.erb within layouts/application (64.3ms)
←[36m2014-01-24T05:27:17.235160+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   Rendered layouts/_header
.html.erb (1.1ms)
←[36m2014-01-24T05:27:17.235552+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Completed 200 OK in 95ms (
Views: 47.3ms | ActiveRecord: 22.5ms)
←[36m2014-01-24T05:27:17.235160+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   Rendered layouts/_header
.html.erb (1.1ms)
←[36m2014-01-24T05:27:17.235552+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Completed 200 OK in 95ms (
Views: 47.3ms | ActiveRecord: 22.5ms)
←[33m2014-01-24T05:27:17.501260+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=info method=GET pat
h=/assets/application-181cdfad867b7ff79ab77b7ed8cc2b59.css host=omr-pinteresting
x.herokuapp.com request_id=5d154d11-1ea3-4b32-b124-2e3fcf22144a fwd="108.227.81.
48" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=6ms status=200 bytes=99534
←[33m2014-01-24T05:27:17.519230+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=info method=GET pat
h=/assets/application-3e804bc17a248fb868fa056958a4fd83.js host=omr-pinterestingx
.herokuapp.com request_id=7cd7bcde-3dc3-4b8a-88ca-8f3c8e74e4ee fwd="108.227.81.4
8" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=7ms status=200 bytes=141097
←[32m2014-01-24T05:27:27.489739+00:00 heroku[api]:←[0m Starting process with com
mand `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by norisjavier@gmail.com
←[35m2014-01-24T05:27:30.799091+00:00 heroku[run.7322]:←[0m Awaiting client
←[35m2014-01-24T05:27:30.829842+00:00 heroku[run.7322]:←[0m Starting process wit
h command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
←[35m2014-01-24T05:27:31.022053+00:00 heroku[run.7322]:←[0m State changed from s
tarting to up
←[35m2014-01-24T05:27:35.520815+00:00 heroku[run.7322]:←[0m Process exited with
status 0
←[35m2014-01-24T05:27:35.534073+00:00 heroku[run.7322]:←[0m State changed from u
p to complete
←[36m2014-01-24T05:27:50.038920+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   Rendered pins/index.html
.erb within layouts/application (6.9ms)
←[36m2014-01-24T05:27:50.030117+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Processing by PinsControll
er#index as HTML
←[36m2014-01-24T05:27:50.027937+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Started GET "/" for 108.22
7.81.48 at 2014-01-24 05:27:50 +0000
←[36m2014-01-24T05:27:50.030117+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Processing by PinsControll
er#index as HTML
←[36m2014-01-24T05:27:50.038920+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   Rendered pins/index.html
.erb within layouts/application (6.9ms)
←[36m2014-01-24T05:27:50.040698+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Completed 200 OK in 10ms (
Views: 4.2ms | ActiveRecord: 5.0ms)
←[36m2014-01-24T05:27:50.040698+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Completed 200 OK in 10ms (
Views: 4.2ms | ActiveRecord: 5.0ms)
←[36m2014-01-24T05:27:50.040257+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   Rendered layouts/_header
.html.erb (0.7ms)
←[36m2014-01-24T05:27:50.040257+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   Rendered layouts/_header
.html.erb (0.7ms)
←[36m2014-01-24T05:27:50.027937+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Started GET "/" for 108.22
7.81.48 at 2014-01-24 05:27:50 +0000
←[33m2014-01-24T05:27:50.043730+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=info method=GET pat
h=/ host=omr-pinterestingx.herokuapp.com request_id=114be963-6367-4dc4-ae80-fd2b
0c4404c4 fwd="108.227.81.48" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=19ms status=304 byte
s=0
←[33m2014-01-24T05:27:50.251339+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=info method=GET pat
h=/assets/application-181cdfad867b7ff79ab77b7ed8cc2b59.css host=omr-pinteresting
x.herokuapp.com request_id=bc73f88b-d742-4ecd-8c46-6d28593cf00f fwd="108.227.81.
48" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=6ms status=304 bytes=0
←[33m2014-01-24T05:27:50.265148+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=info method=GET pat
h=/assets/application-3e804bc17a248fb868fa056958a4fd83.js host=omr-pinterestingx
.herokuapp.com request_id=7c09708a-ab5e-40f1-a578-8cbd8a50d238 fwd="108.227.81.4
8" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=0
←[36m2014-01-24T05:39:15.281248+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Started GET "/" for 108.22
7.81.48 at 2014-01-24 05:39:15 +0000
←[36m2014-01-24T05:39:15.281248+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Started GET "/" for 108.22
7.81.48 at 2014-01-24 05:39:15 +0000
←[36m2014-01-24T05:39:15.282548+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Processing by PinsControll
er#index as HTML
←[36m2014-01-24T05:39:15.282548+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Processing by PinsControll
er#index as HTML
←[36m2014-01-24T05:39:15.290690+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   Rendered pins/index.html
.erb within layouts/application (6.7ms)
←[36m2014-01-24T05:39:15.292301+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   Rendered layouts/_header
.html.erb (0.7ms)
←[36m2014-01-24T05:39:15.290690+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   Rendered pins/index.html
.erb within layouts/application (6.7ms)
←[36m2014-01-24T05:39:15.292374+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   Rendered layouts/_header
.html.erb (0.7ms)
←[36m2014-01-24T05:39:15.292828+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Completed 200 OK in 10ms (
Views: 4.2ms | ActiveRecord: 5.0ms)
←[36m2014-01-24T05:39:15.292930+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Completed 200 OK in 10ms (
Views: 4.2ms | ActiveRecord: 5.0ms)
←[33m2014-01-24T05:39:15.297080+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=info method=GET pat
h=/ host=omr-pinterestingx.herokuapp.com request_id=e5e731a4-2e38-4dc3-9bd4-f16d
d70b6d6f fwd="108.227.81.48" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=18ms status=304 byte
s=0
←[33m2014-01-24T05:39:15.726275+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=info method=GET pat
h=/assets/application-181cdfad867b7ff79ab77b7ed8cc2b59.css host=omr-pinteresting
x.herokuapp.com request_id=dbadec13-1ea9-419d-84d0-018366c1d2df fwd="108.227.81.
48" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=13ms status=200 bytes=99534
←[33m2014-01-24T05:39:15.736938+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=info method=GET pat
h=/assets/application-3e804bc17a248fb868fa056958a4fd83.js host=omr-pinterestingx
.herokuapp.com request_id=be9f3e8f-22cd-46f8-a38e-70499e520bbb fwd="108.227.81.4
8" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=6ms status=304 bytes=0
←[36m2014-01-24T05:39:20.124660+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Started DELETE "/users/sig
n_out" for 108.227.81.48 at 2014-01-24 05:39:20 +0000
←[36m2014-01-24T05:39:20.124660+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Started DELETE "/users/sig
n_out" for 108.227.81.48 at 2014-01-24 05:39:20 +0000
←[36m2014-01-24T05:39:20.126980+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Processing by Devise::Sess
ionsController#destroy as HTML
←[36m2014-01-24T05:39:20.126980+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   Parameters: {"authentici
ty_token"=>"1AVdG1oEBZrR2kBVmArxtsQfDriMwhdxepobzVeZjUo="}
←[36m2014-01-24T05:39:20.127074+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   Parameters: {"authentici
ty_token"=>"1AVdG1oEBZrR2kBVmArxtsQfDriMwhdxepobzVeZjUo="}
←[36m2014-01-24T05:39:20.126980+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Processing by Devise::Sess
ionsController#destroy as HTML
←[33m2014-01-24T05:39:20.202045+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=info method=POST pa
th=/users/sign_out host=omr-pinterestingx.herokuapp.com request_id=a0332921-4adc
-4f55-ac16-1d76b01116b8 fwd="108.227.81.48" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=86ms
status=302 bytes=105
←[36m2014-01-24T05:39:20.196532+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Redirected to http://omr-p
interestingx.herokuapp.com/
←[36m2014-01-24T05:39:20.196789+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Completed 302 Found in 70m
s (ActiveRecord: 6.1ms)
←[36m2014-01-24T05:39:20.196532+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Redirected to http://omr-p
interestingx.herokuapp.com/
←[36m2014-01-24T05:39:20.188336+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m [deprecated] I18n.enforce_
available_locales will default to true in the future. If you really want to skip
 validation of your locale you can set I18n.enforce_available_locales = false to
 avoid this message.
←[36m2014-01-24T05:39:20.196735+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Completed 302 Found in 70m
s (ActiveRecord: 6.1ms)
←[36m2014-01-24T05:39:20.570672+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   Rendered pages/_home.htm
l.erb (1.0ms)
←[36m2014-01-24T05:39:20.555106+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Started GET "/" for 108.22
7.81.48 at 2014-01-24 05:39:20 +0000
←[36m2014-01-24T05:39:20.555106+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Started GET "/" for 108.22
7.81.48 at 2014-01-24 05:39:20 +0000
←[36m2014-01-24T05:39:20.556383+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Processing by PinsControll
er#index as HTML
←[36m2014-01-24T05:39:20.573939+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   Rendered pins/index.html
.erb within layouts/application (16.1ms)
←[36m2014-01-24T05:39:20.556383+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Processing by PinsControll
er#index as HTML
←[36m2014-01-24T05:39:20.573939+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   Rendered pins/index.html
.erb within layouts/application (16.1ms)
←[36m2014-01-24T05:39:20.575704+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   Rendered layouts/_header
.html.erb (1.0ms)
←[36m2014-01-24T05:39:20.575704+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   Rendered layouts/_header
.html.erb (1.0ms)
←[36m2014-01-24T05:39:20.570672+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   Rendered pages/_home.htm
l.erb (1.0ms)
←[36m2014-01-24T05:39:20.576180+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Completed 200 OK in 20ms (
Views: 16.1ms | ActiveRecord: 2.5ms)
←[36m2014-01-24T05:39:20.576180+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Completed 200 OK in 20ms (
Views: 16.1ms | ActiveRecord: 2.5ms)
←[33m2014-01-24T05:39:20.578835+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=info method=GET pat
h=/ host=omr-pinterestingx.herokuapp.com request_id=105ba383-0040-4647-b888-7790
9123694f fwd="108.227.81.48" dyno=web.1 connect=10ms service=30ms status=200 byt
es=1928
←[36m2014-01-24T05:42:07.219371+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   Rendered pins/index.html
.erb within layouts/application (6.6ms)
←[36m2014-01-24T05:42:07.219371+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   Rendered pins/index.html
.erb within layouts/application (6.6ms)
←[36m2014-01-24T05:42:07.221931+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Completed 200 OK in 16ms (
Views: 10.7ms | ActiveRecord: 2.6ms)
←[36m2014-01-24T05:42:07.221931+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Completed 200 OK in 16ms (
Views: 10.7ms | ActiveRecord: 2.6ms)
←[36m2014-01-24T05:42:07.203780+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Started GET "/" for 108.22
7.81.48 at 2014-01-24 05:42:07 +0000
←[36m2014-01-24T05:42:07.203560+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Started GET "/" for 108.22
7.81.48 at 2014-01-24 05:42:07 +0000
←[36m2014-01-24T05:42:07.205899+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Processing by PinsControll
er#index as HTML
←[36m2014-01-24T05:42:07.215560+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   Rendered pages/_home.htm
l.erb (1.0ms)
←[36m2014-01-24T05:42:07.205687+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Processing by PinsControll
er#index as HTML
←[36m2014-01-24T05:42:07.215560+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   Rendered pages/_home.htm
l.erb (1.0ms)
←[36m2014-01-24T05:42:07.221542+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   Rendered layouts/_header
.html.erb (1.5ms)
←[36m2014-01-24T05:42:07.221542+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   Rendered layouts/_header
.html.erb (1.5ms)
←[33m2014-01-24T05:42:07.455010+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=info method=GET pat
h=/assets/application-181cdfad867b7ff79ab77b7ed8cc2b59.css host=omr-pinteresting
x.herokuapp.com request_id=71800b84-1658-4f60-a257-fa56f4ade2ba fwd="108.227.81.
48" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=6ms status=304 bytes=0
←[33m2014-01-24T05:42:07.466827+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=info method=GET pat
h=/assets/application-3e804bc17a248fb868fa056958a4fd83.js host=omr-pinterestingx
.herokuapp.com request_id=560eea6e-650c-4b47-ad6b-1eee25c6cc9c fwd="108.227.81.4
8" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=4ms status=304 bytes=0
←[33m2014-01-24T05:42:07.227755+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=info method=GET pat
h=/ host=omr-pinterestingx.herokuapp.com request_id=31a5b45f-ff03-4d6d-be30-7c45
280a0b43 fwd="108.227.81.48" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=34ms status=200 byte
s=1864
```

Comment: how did you understand that the old version is active?

Comment: on my localhost its all up to date and working perfectly but when I push to heroku master & heroku open a good amount of things are not showing up..

Comment: did you try to update a browser's page by clicking update button?

Comment: did you commit your code before pushing?

Comment: @maijoa yes tried that, nothing

Comment: @sevenseacat yes I did

Comment: I've just realized that on my Huroku the name of my application is pinterestingx(pinterestingx.herokuapp.com) but when I git push heroku master my address bar says http://omr-pinterestingx.herokuapp.com/ so they don't match, might this be the problem?

Comment: Disregard the comment on top, that wasn't it. The problem was with the command i passed to set my amazon bucket differed from what was in my text editor production environment... so nothing image related worked.. Fixed now! Thx